# Kali Linux login as guest

Tags: linux, login

I recently installed steam on kali but I am logged in as root so it wont let me use it. How do I login as guest or another user?
I tried using guest/nopassword or user/live. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check users you have on your system:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

If there is no ordinary user just create new one:

```
useradd -d /home/<username> <username>
passwd <username>
```

and then switch to this user